# Association name direction in UML use case diagram

Tags: uml

What exactly means the association name direction (painted as a black triangle near the association name) in UML use case diagram? And what's the difference between it and association direction?

Let me paste some link that explains what exactly I'm asking about:

http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bwtg6A48dQQjODBlNTJiNzQtYmE1OC00YmViLTk3ZGEtYjQ1MDYwMDFkZTIz&sort=name&layout=list&num=50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solid triangle next to the association name just informs the reader about the direction in which the association should be read for the association name to make sense. For instance an association "LivesIn" between Person and City could be read either as "City LivesIn Person" or "Person LivesIn City". In this case, the reading direction of the association in order to make sense is clear, but in other situations it may be more ambiguous. If we want to clarify how the association should be read, then we can indicate that by means of adding the small black triangle next to the name pointing in the desired direction.

This does not affect the semantic of the association.

Answer (score 0):

In the usecase diagram you don't usually show aggregation/composition but only simple association link with no arrows at the end. 
You have four kinds of association in the class diagram:
- bidirectional
- undirectional
- aggregation
- composition

btw, I never asked myself why we don't show full association type, multiplicty, associations ends etc...in the usecase diagram ? This is strange.

Comment: Thanks for response. I realize, that it is not a common thing to show arrows at the ends of associations in use case diagrams, but it sometimes helps to understand whether an actor is an initiator or a beneficiary of a use case. The arrow indicates what control flow is in it. This is what I'm aware of.
My question is, what does association name direction means. It's symbol is a black triangle near the association name.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the small arrows on the text of an association are for readability, a hint as to the direction the text should read.  The below example is for class diagrams but the same would be true for a use case diagram.  I've never seen a good example of when to use them on a use case diagram though.

The association direction indicates the direction of visibility.  If a pilot flies multiple flights in one day, do you want to go to the pilot to get the list of his flights
[image: pilot and his flights]

or go to the flight to find the pilot?
[image: Flight and its pilot]

Sometimes it's easier to indicate in the association which way to read it with no direction arrow on the association line itself.
[image: Association with directional name]

Comment: So, from your response, I understand, that there is no difference whether the arrow is on the association line or the triangle is near the association name. It means the same thing. Isn't it?

Comment: The arrow at the tip of the line usually is for the direction of visibilty while a small arrow on the name of the association is to clarify the relationship.  In pic#3 'flown by >>' doesn't mean that the flight has visibility to its pilot, it means the association should be read as X [Flight] is flown by Y [Pilot]

Comment: We should not confuse navigability with readability. Readability only facilitates the comprehension of the model by a human but has no effect on the semantics of the model. Navigability, instead, has a clear impact on the system generated from that model (it restricts how the objects can interact)